# Unable to insert record in main table without lookup record even with null foreign key MVC EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, data-annotations, nullable

Here's my two classes. The `SellPrice` records are populated first and then using information in the `SellPrice` records the `BuyPrice` records inserted from a JSON request. There are many `SellPrice` records to each `BuyPrice` record.

I want to be able to have the `SellPrice` records inserted first but even though I have set the `SellPrice` foreign key to nullable it still wont let me save `SellPrice` records without a lookup record in `BuyPrice`.

I want to be able to constantly delete and update all the `BuyPrice` records on a `BuyPrice` JSON data fetch cycle every second or so.

I am really new to this and would like to be able to do this using Data Annotations rather than the fluent method.

Many thanks. It's driving me nuts!

```
public class SellPrice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime EventDateTime { get; set; }
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public String EventName { get; set; }
    public string MarketId { get; set; }
    public String MarketName { get; set; }
    public String SelectionId { get; set; }
    public String SelectionName { get; set; }
    public String SellerName { get; set; }
    public String SellPrice { get; set; }

    public BuyPrice BuyPrice { get; set; }
    public int? BuyPriceId { get; set; }
}

public class BuyPrice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string MarketId { get; set; }
    public string SelectionId { get; set; }
    public float BuyPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I have changed the names of Model to make it easier to understand the relationship so the the error message is referring to actual structures. The principle is the same - how to be able to insert child records with no corresponding parent record.

[image]

Comment: did you run the data migration after the above change ?

Comment: If you have a FK relationship, then you **cannot** insert child records without a parent - that's the **whole point** of having a FK relationship - to ensure no invalid "ghost" data is inserted !

Comment: Thank you @marc_s - i have managed to change the design so that the parent is at least partially created first and then the child is created inheriting the key to maintain data integrity as you recommend.

Much appreciated.